# Como limpar o campo de Foreign Keys no SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se existe como limpar a referência do user_id/store_id presente na tabela

> user_store

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`(
`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store`(
`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)ENGINE INNODB DEFAULT CHAR SET 'utf8' AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_store`(
`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`store_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `user`(`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_store_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`)
    REFERENCES `store`(`id`)
)ENGINE INNODB DEFAULT CHAR SET 'utf8' AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
```

Comment: Você se refere a remover as constraints fk_user_id e fk_store_id ou apenas remover os dados (valores) das tabelas referenciadas?

Comment: Por exemplo se o usuario remover sua loja, o user_store deveria ficar com o id normal e user_id, o store_id seria zerado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para remover as referencias de chaves estrangeiras você pode fazer:

```
ALTER TABLE nome_tabela  DROP FOREIGN KEY nome_constraint;
```

Caso você queira apagar apenas o dados (registros) você pode fazer um delete table na tabela user_store:

```
DELETE FROM nome_tabela
```